# Get the value from java object

Tags: java, solrj

Using the below code

```
Object str = response.getHeader().get("parms");
```

I get the flowing response

```
params={q=catlevel0:sales (1105),facet.field=catlevel3,facet.mincount=1,fq=catlevel2:and (35),facet=true,wt=xml,version=2.2}
```

How can i get value for "q", "facet.field", "fq"

Please help..

Comment: Please improve your question's title. Your current title is unintelligible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the following code

```
NamedList<Object> results = (NamedList<Object>) response.getHeader().get("params");

for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("restuls: " + i + " " + results.getName(i) + " : " + results.getVal(i));
}
```

you can get all your params. If you want explicitly q, facet.field, fq you can compare results.getName(i) with q, facet.field, fq ie with q

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {

   if ("q".equals(results.getName(i))){
      System.out.println(results.getVal(i));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps